# refreshing a datatable

Tags: jsf, datatable, refresh

dudes, does any of you know how to do this?

i have a page that has a datatable on it.  it has a button to delete a row.  the button works as expected, when you click it, it will delete the selected row/s.  i also have another button that opens a popup window where you search for items and them add them to the said datatable.  i am having a hard time figuring out how to refresh the datatable once you click the "select" button on the popup window.

my solution is having a hidden button that will refresh the datatable.  it works when i litterally click it.  but when i trigger the click event on the popup window using javascript, it doesnt always work.  sometime it refreshes, sometimes it doesnt.

what's actually the best way to refresh a datatable?

Comment: which jsf version are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use JSF2.0, there is an option to update part of your application with

```
<h:form>
...
...(here you have the binding data)
<h:commandButton action="#{yourbean.updateRows}" >
<f:ajax render="tableName" />
</h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

**EDITED**

If you want to invoke it from JAVASCRIPT use:

```
document.getElementById('elementName').click();
```

Comment: thanks. this is actually my current solution, but is there a way of calling that commandButton through javascript? i have used this: popup window: opener.refreshDataTable();   then on my parent window (the one containing the datatable to refresh): function refreshDataTable() {
   $('.addOcc').click();
   var btn = document.getElementById("mainForm:dt:composite_dataTable_dt");
   btn.click();
  }

Comment: Sure! see my updated answer! and don't forget to check for accepted answer!(click on the green arrow)

Answer (score 0):

How are you accessing your DataTable in the popup window ? by keeping it in some session variable and in you parent page are you displaying the datatable through some UI Component like GridView ? In that case you can reload your parent window from where you opned the popu windo through javascript. E.g. window.opener.location.reload();

Comment: thanks for the reply.  yep i do store it in session.  my other option is actually to just reload the entire page, however, since i have noticed that clicking on the "delete" button actually deletes the row i have selected and then refreshes the datatable without refreshing the entire page, maybe theres something i can do to actually just refresh the datatable once the "select" button on the popup window is clicked.

Answer (score -2):

I can think of .. `Datatable.AcceptChanges();` But that's for C#..